# Parse :: Sender is not allowed to send messages. Android Push Notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a problem sending push notifications in Andoid using Parse. I have a project in iOS and I recive all push notifications perfectly. But in Android, when I want to send a Push Notification using parse platform I recive the following message:

`Sender is not allowed to send messages.`

Any tips?

Best Regards!

Comment: Did you check your sender id and api key?

Comment: have you enabled client push under settings in parse? By default a user/device is not aloud to send a push notification

Comment: I am getting the same issue - any luck figuring this out @rici?

Comment: @ChrisHume: The only thing I know about parse.com is that it has nothing to do with [tag:parsing]